What's the XML/JSON format for GSTR-1 & GSTR-3B?
I am building automation for filing the GSTR-1 & GSTR-3B
XML format for filing GSTR-1 & GSTR-3B.
if not XML then JSON
A format for filing B2C GSTR-1 & GSTR-3B.
Where can I find XML/json formats for GSTR?
GST portal doesn't have that

GST is an application for doing India Taxes.  See following for schemas that are used to generate the XML : https://cbic-gst.gov.in/aces/download.html
